# How to make chosen menu disabled by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-chosen

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rz2es/64/), I have an example of jquery-chosen with modal dialog. What I want is on first open of the dialog, the chosen to not show the items. I read the documentation and I don't find anything.

So in the current example the modal options should be closed after running the fiddle example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog">
  <label for="options1">Modal Options</label>
  <select id="options1" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    <option value="7">Option 7</option>
  </select>
</div>

<label for="options1">Options</label>
<select id="options2">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
  <option value="6">Option 6</option>
  <option value="7">Option 7</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $("select").chosen();
    $("#dialog").dialog({modal: true, width:400, height:"auto"});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call jQuery chosen after calling dialog.

```
$(function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog({modal: true, width:400, height:"auto"});
    $("select").chosen();
});
```